# BuildMaster - FTP - How to include or exclude a file type

Tags: ftp, buildmaster

Is there a way to **exclude** a file? I would like to ***exclude*** all *.config files. Everything else should be included.

Or if I could say **include**: `*.aspx, *.ascx, *.xml, *.png, *.gif, *.html` that would be fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To quote what Tod said in this [forum post](http://inedo.com/support/questions/2109):

> I'm not sure the component we use to FTP supports negated wildcards,
>   but you can simply add a Delete Files action before this that operates
>   on *.config
>
> Alternatively (if you don't want to delete because you may re-use the
>   files), you can use the Synchronize/Transfer Files action to a
>   temporary directory (e.g. ~\Ftp) and use a !*.config mask on that to
>   not transfer the configs, then use the FTP action from ~\Ftp as the
>   source directory.